# Javascript: Mathematical operation methods

Tags: javascript

On this code, the first alert box is displaying `-3`, am just thinking of this. How can this be possible? As to my knowledge on this, is should alert `-2`, where i am lacking to understand this? please

```
var x = 6; var y=8;
alert(x++-++y);
alert(x);alert(y);
```

Comment: What exactly is surprising about this? Have you consulted any sort of reference material to investigate how the `++` operator works?

Answer (score 1):

The `++` unary operator — a legacy from C, maybe B, maybe PL/I — can be used either as a *pre-increment* or a *post-increment* operator. If it's placed *after* an l-value (a variable reference), the value of the expression is the value of the variable *before* it has been incremented. The expression has the side-effect of incrementing the variable's value and storing it back.

Thus:

- the value of `x++` is `6`, because that's the value of `x` *before* being incremented.
- the value of `++y` is `9`, because the `++` operator is being used to *pre-increment* the variable `y`
- `6 - 9` is `-3`

Many computer instruction set architectures have included pre- and post-increment addressing modes for machine registers and/or memory locations to facilitate various tasks, notably the process of loading values from an area of memory and incrementing an address register in preparation for fetching the next value. I have always strongly suspected that those concepts seeped upwards into higher-level languages to provide analogous conveniences.

Answer (score 0):

```
x++ => 6 // postfix
++y => 9 // prefix
```

so `6 - 9 = -3`

According to [Postfix / Increment (++) documentation on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Arithmetic_Operators#Increment_(.2B.2B)):

> - If used postfix, with operator after operand (for example, x++), then it returns the value before incrementing.
> - If used prefix with operator before operand (for example, ++x), then it returns the value after incrementing.

Answer (score 0):

There is a difference between the statement `x++` and the statement `++x`. It is that the former will return the *original* value of x while the latter will return the `new` value of x.

As a result, the calculation comes to 6 (the starting value of x) minus 9 (the new value of y).

Answer (score 0):

leading `++` will add 1 to the value after the operation whilst trailing `++` will apply it before the operation. Hence `6-9=-3`

Answer (score 0):

x++ returns the value *before* incrementing, 6.

++y returns the value *after* incrementing, 9.

6 - 9 = -3

Answer (score 0):

x++ does not change the x value until after the operation, so it is 6.

++y changes the value before the operation, so the value becomes 9.

The first alert therefore shows -3.

The second alert is not helpful because you are seeing the now-altered value of x (7) instead of 6.